# Cats EitherT convert to Future[Result]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have result like:

```
EitherT[Future, IllegalStateException, Result]
```

how to convert to Future[Result] ?
And let Future fail with this IllegalStateException ?
I know I can do like resultT.value to get Future[Either[Exception, Res]] and convert it but maybe there is simpler way.

Answer (score 5):

As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/EitherT.html#rethrowT(implicitF:cats.MonadError%5BF,_%3E:A%5D):F%5BB%5D) is your friend.

> `def rethrowT(implicit F: MonadError[F, _ >: A]): F[B]`
>
> Given `MonadError[F, E :> A]` transforms `Either[F, A, B]` to `F[B]` If the value was `B`, `F[B]` is successful If the value was `A`, `F[B]` is failed with `E`.

All you need to do is:

```scala
resultT.rethrowT
```